# mysqli_fetch_array & row expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm new to SQL and I'm trying to set up a log-in system. I've followed a guide but I'm getting these 2 messages when I try to login:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginguide/login.php on line 13
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginguide\login.php on line 16

I created a database on MyPHPAdmin however, I don't know how to do that properly either, am I meant to add tables to that database?

Here's the login.php code:

```
<?php
   include("config.php");
   session_start();

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      // username and password sent from form 

      $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
      $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 

      $sql = "SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username = '$myusername' and passcode = '$mypassword'";
      $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $active = $row['active'];

      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

      if($count == 1) {
         session_register("myusername");
         $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;

         header("location: welcome.php");
      }else {
         $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
      }
   }
?>
<html>

   <head>
      <title>Login Page</title>

      <style type = "text/css">
         body {
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size:14px;
         }

         label {
            font-weight:bold;
            width:100px;
            font-size:14px;
         }

         .box {
            border:#666666 solid 1px;
         }
      </style>

   </head>

   <body bgcolor = "#FFFFFF">

      <div align = "center">
         <div style = "width:300px; border: solid 1px #333333; " align = "left">
            <div style = "background-color:#333333; color:#FFFFFF; padding:3px;"><b>Login</b></div>

            <div style = "margin:30px">

               <form action = "" method = "post">
                  <label>UserName  :</label><input type = "text" name = "username" class = "box"/><br /><br />
                  <label>Password  :</label><input type = "password" name = "password" class = "box" /><br/><br />
                  <input type = "submit" value = " Submit "/><br />
               </form>

               <div style="font-size:11px;<?php echo $error; ?></div>

            </div>

         </div>

      </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli\_fetch\_array()/mysqli\_fetch\_assoc()/mysqli\_fetch\_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource or mysqli\_result, boolean given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysqli-fetch-array-mysqli-fetch-assoc-mysqli-fetch-row-expects-parameter-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You need to include column "active" in your SQL query or just replace 'id' with an *

```
select * from admin where ....
(or)
select id, active from admin where ....
```

2) Check your config.php file that you have included in the given example, you could get that warning if the DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE names are given wrong(grammatical mistakes).

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'testDB');
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your query is failing and returning a false value. Check your query and if it is working fine, put this in your code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

if (!$result) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($db));
    exit();
}
```

for more information.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score -2):

You only select id, and you use "active"

So you should fix that first:

```
SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '$myusername' and passcode = '$mypassword'
```

It should work now